# Merge adjacent polygons & concatenate attribute values (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, merge, concatenation

In QGIS 3.16.  I have a layer of 1000+ polygons, many of which are adjacent (touching, overlapping, or one completely inside another).  If all of the adjacent polygons are merged, I will end up with between 100 and 200 (larger) polygons.

I would like to accomplish this in a way that preserves all of the attributes for all polygons, for example:

1. For polygons being merged: values for attribute X are concatenated for the resulting polygon.  (Example: For attribute 'status', Polygon A has value "IC" and Polygon B has value "NC".   If these two polygons merge into Polygon AB, I would like the corresponding value of attribute 'status' to be "IC, NC".)
2. For polygons *not* being merged (i.e. isolated ones without an adjacent neighbor) there is no change to their attributes.

This seems like a fairly common task that it should be possible to accomplish, but my searches have been fruitless thus far.

I'd like to stay within QGIS if possible (I have never used PostGIS before).  If your answer involves SQL or Python, please consider that I am learning these now but an absolute beginner, so I will not understand code without context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using only QGIS, you can achieve this as follows:

1. Dissolve all polygons
2. Apply `Multipart to singleparts` to the dissolved polygons: you get one feature for each connected group of polygons.
3. On the orginal layer, create a new field named `grouped` that adds a unique identifier for the group of polygons each of the original polygon features is part of. Use this expression in the field calculator: `array_first (overlay_intersects( 'singleparts', $id))` where `singleparts` is the name of the layer created in step 2.
4. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate` with the original polygon layer as input to dissolve all features based on the `group` field created in step 3.

*Screenshot: see original adjacent polygons (touching, overlapping, within another), labeled with their value for the `status` attribute and the `group` as calculated in step 3. The Aggregate dialog shows `Group by expression` that based on this `grouped` attribute, the polygons are dissolved. Below, you can choose how each attribute will be aggregated: for `status`, select `concatenate` and make sure the field length (second last column) is long enough (in my case, 10 was too short, I manually had to change it: I set the value to 100).*
[image]

*Result: three single features, labeled with the (concatenated) `status` attribute:*
[image]

Comment: Babel, you are being extraordinarily helpful to me this/last week and I appreciate it very much.  Thanks!  I understand the principle of what you're suggesting, but my attempts to implement step #3 are yielding a column with all NULL values. (Strangely, the field calculator seems to be getting values as the output preview shows a number in brackets...)  The same behavior occurs: 1) whether the simpleparts layer (with my name) is temporary or saved to a .shp;  2) whether I use $id or a field "id" that I created in that .shp;   3) whether the new 'grouped' field is type Integer or String.

Comment: Sorry, you're right: the output of `overlay_intersects()` is an array. To get the number, you must add an `array_first ()` function. I changed my anser accordingly.

Comment: This worked for the ID (step 3)! Unfortunately the polygon groups do not exactly match the features created during step 2: in some cases a polygon is in one group for the 'singleparts' layer, and another group in the 'grouped' field in the original layer.  I can't upload an image in the comment but the cases I'm seeing of this are where two polygons appear to be touching at exactly one vertex (and are also touching other polygons); the smaller of the two polygons is inconsistently grouped.

Comment: You can edit your original question to upload a screenshot (if you than copy the link in edit mode and paste it to comments, to can avoid publishing the image there). I'm not quite sure how the problem looks and how you want to have it resolved. I added two polygons that touche other polygons at exactlyy one vertiex, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ31S.png

Comment: I think I have solved my above issue via the following method: from the original layer, create a buffer layer of distance 0,01m; then use that buffer layer for the rest of your sequence.  The polygons that touch at a single node are subsequently grouped together, which was not the case before.  If anyone has further suggestions, feel free to share them. Otherwise, thanks again Babel!

Comment: OK, still struggling  :)   On step #4 (aggregation) I am getting an evaluation error.  Doesn't seem to be related to field length or delimiter.  Could it be related to NULL values in some fields?  I will try to investigate this but I've got a lot of fields...

Comment: Where do you get the error message and what does it say exactly? Where do you have `NULL` values?

Comment: Error: immediately upon running the aggregation tool.  It says "Evaluation error in expression "concatenate("ID_CH", "Complexe", TRUE, ',')": Impossible de calculer l’agrégat pour : ID_CH   L’exécution a échoué après 0.97 secondes"  (sorry for the French but it should be self explanatory).   Null values:  my layer is formed from various other layers that were merged; some fields were common and some were not.  For the fields that were not in common, some features have a value and others are empty (say "NULL" in them). I was thinking to eventually fill in, but haven't yet.

Comment: I guess `Complexe` here refers to data type? Did you set the data type for the field you want to concatenate to text (string) as can be seen on my first screenshot? Otherwise, QGIS can't create an entry (characters can't be stored in a "numbers only" field).

Comment: Complexe is the name of the field I am grouping by (the "grouped" field).  Every field I want to concatenate is set to text (string) with a length of 254.  However, some of those fields were initially integer (I don't think that matters).  I have about 40 fields that I am setting to 'concatenate' so I suppose the problem could be in one of them.  (Some have many empty/null values.) I am trying different things but still getting the same error message after about 1 second.

Comment: OK, from far it's difficult to see what's going wrong. Could you upload a screenshot and/or provide sample data to reproduce the problem?

Comment: it looks like I am having a few different kinds of problems with the aggregate function, and perhaps it is better if I post a separate question about the aggregate function rather than drag it out in the comments.  I will mark this question as answered because it seems it is a good way to solve my original problem (though, if I am unable to actually solve it this way due to this issue, I will return and reopen the question).  Thanks again.