# Aggregating intersecting polygons into one in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, overlapping-features, polygon-creation, aggregate

In QGIS 3.16 I have one layer with a lot of single polygons and some of them intersect.

I want to aggregate these intersecting polygons to one single polygon. As a result i need the size of the connected polygons. None of the intersecting polygons have a shared  value in the attribute table, which the other polygons which are not intersecting (and therefor don t need to be grouped/aggregated/merged) don't also have.

Is there a similar tool to ArcGIS Aggregate?

Comment: You could `dissolve` and then run `multi to single part`. This will remove the attributes, though.

Comment: @Erik, I think you can put it as a valid answer

Comment: Not unless OP states, whether they need to keep the attributes or not @Taras

Comment: Yes agree, but returning attributes is not a big deal!

Comment: Hi, yep it would be good to keep the attributes-if its easy to return them then I would go with the proposed way. How is it not a big deal to return the attributes? Thanks-i will update the question later including this question...

Comment: This seems to be very similar: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396362/88814 - does it help?

Comment: Babel, thank you so much for the link, this seems to be the way it should work!. But I have another small problem now, I get the message "Feature could not be written to Aggregated...: Could not store attribute "OBJART": String of length 3530 exceeds maximum field length (5)". when I try to aggregate the layer according to the grouped values. how can i just set the length of the field to an indefinite length? Or does that limitation have an important role?

Comment: The field `OBJART` has a length of just 5 characters, but concatenating all attribtues, the resulting string has a length of 3530. That's why the field-length has to be longer. In my lineked answer, on the first screenshot, you have a red box. The second last has `100` in it: this is the length. Change this value to something above 3530.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Babel send this link: [Merge adjacent polygons & concatenate attribute values (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396361/merge-adjacent-polygons-concatenate-attribute-values-qgis)

It worked for me like that, thank you very much!

Comment: If you do not mind, I am voting to close your question a duplicate to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396361/merge-adjacent-polygons-concatenate-attribute-values-qgis, since you have found an answer in a different thread.

Comment: I think it will be easier you you do it :)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I don't know how to do that, I am quite new to this forum. Could u give me a hint where I do this?

Comment: No worries, I was also new to this forum. Please check underneath your question there is a button `Close`